# ##[error]WelderDBWebApp\Properties\licenses.licx(1,0): Error LC0003: Unable to resolve type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadListBox, Telerik.Web.UI,Version=2015

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, telerik

I am using Azure DevOps to build my project, and I am facing an error which states..

> ##[error]WelderDBWebApp\Properties\licenses.licx(1,0): Error LC0003: Unable to resolve type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadListBox, Telerik.Web.UI,
> Version=2015.2.729.40, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4'

My asp.net framework application is working fine locally, but in Azure DevOps shows above message ..

I have deleted .licx file, but after which a new error shows up which is ..

> ##[error]WelderDBWebApp\NDTRecon\NDTWorksManagement.aspx.cs(9,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Telerik' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Note:- I have created a service connection and NuGet.config file. Even updated Web.config file

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the license compiler at [Lc.exe (License Compiler)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/lc-exe-license-compiler?redirectedfrom=MSDN) states ：

"A .licx text file is automatically generated or updated by the Windows Forms Designer whenever a licensed control is added to the form. As part of compilation, the project system will transform the .licx text file into a .licenses binary resource that provides support for .NET control licensing. The binary resource will then be embedded in the project output."

Along the same lines, [TX Text Control .NET Licensing Explained](https://www.textcontrol.com/blog/2015/07/10/tx-text-control-net-licensing-explained/) indicates that manual creation is only necessary when you are dynamically creating the control.